# do you know any free reporting services like devexpress or boldreports?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, reporting-services, report, reporting

do you know any free reporting services like devexpress or boldreports? I'm working on a big project with a friend of mine and the app requires a lot of reports for the users. I use React on the front end and my friend uses ASP.net web API on the backend. do you know any free or cheap reporting library?

I tried BoldReports but it kinda expensive for me?